# Importing Project Tango .obj to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Using the Constructor app on the Project Tango development kit I created a mesh of my kitchen and exported it to .obj which works fine in other software such as MeshUp and MicroStation.
I followed the steps in [Import your mesh to Unity](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/tools/constructor#import_your_mesh_into_unity) but nothing comes in Unity.

For the Unity project I used a blank project without any other asset in the scene. Changing the scale and texture didn't help. When focusing (f on selected when the mouse cursor is over the scene) does focus but again, nothing shows. Importing other .obj files work fine - with or without textures.

What's displayed in Unity:

[image]

What's displayed in MeshLab:

[image]

UPDATE:

converting it to .fbx using AutoDesk FBX Converter 2013.3 failed with the error: "Not enough parameters".

Comment: Want to share the OBJ file? Is there also a MTL File? Try and right click and re-import it. And show us what the inspector displays when you select it.

Comment: BTW I mean select the actual OBJ in your project. From the screenshot you posted with the prefab selected it is clear it has no mesh. So something went wrong with the file you tried to import.

Comment: @peterept no mtl file, happy to share the obj but currently in a corporate network so Drive, DropBox and alike are blocked...

Comment: OBJ files are text files, paste it into https://gist.github.com/

Comment: thanks for the tip. it's 30MB so wouldn't work even when dropping the file to pre-populate the text. will share it tonight

Comment: oh, well that's large alright - that may have been too much for Unity to handle importing... you may need to mesh reduce it, or try another format such as FBX.

Comment: @peterept fbx conversion didn't work but it led me to the answer in [this](https://plus.google.com/112724713796176995659/posts/hcMvBxWteus) discussion. Running it through the [3D model repair service](https://modelrepair.azurewebsites.net/) solved the issue. Not brilliant but an acceptable solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107082/discussion-between-hen-wagner-and-peterept).

Comment: is there any update for this question?

Comment: hi @Mohammad May, have you tried Microsoft's repair service mentioned? that's what worked for me.

Comment: Hey @HenWagner I tried importing into Meshlab, exporting as .ply, importing in Blender and exporting as .fbx, Once again importing in Unity3d and selecting the vertex shader. Quite cumbersome but works!